# Conditional Probability of multiple throws

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Given 50/50 odds for each chance, what is the probability that I will amass 10 wins before loosing 5-in-a-row.

Downvote for what?  I'm looking more for an approach to solving this than the actual answer.

Comment: You are getting downvotes because you have not shown that you even tried.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe thanks for the tip.  I have tried to think it through with no luck.  I have heard "complementary probability" may be a good avenue, but probability is not my strong suit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need 10 wins in total. For each win, you can have a sequence that looks like one of the following:
W, LW, LLW, LLLW, LLLLW
So, let $A = \{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5) | \forall i, x_i \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0} \text{ and }\sum x_i = 10\}$
In other words, $A$ is the set of all 5-tuples representing solutions to the Diophantine equation: $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=10$ with nonnegative integers.

Then, the total probability is:

$$\sum_{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5) \in A}\dfrac{10!}{x_1!x_2!x_3!x_4!x_5!}2^{-(x_1+2x_2+3x_3+4x_4+5x_5)}$$

Using R, I calculate that the probability is about 72.7976%.

You can find the same answer with WA:

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BSum%5BSum%5BSum%5B10!%2F(a!*b!*c!*d!*(10-a-b-c-d)!)*2%5E(-a-2b-3c-4d-5(10-a-b-c-d)),%7Bd,0,10-a-b-c%7D%5D,%7Bc,0,10-a-b%7D%5D,%7Bb,0,10-a%7D%5D,%7Ba,0,10%7D%5D)

To give a little more detail (and hopefully help you understand it), we have 10 "slots" for wins. In each slot, we can have anywhere from 0 to 4 losses before the win. So, the total number of "ways" to get to ten wins while never getting 5 or more losses is $5^{10}$. However, for each "way", the number of games played matters, and you need the specific order of wins and losses for each.

So, for example, 10 wins with no losses has a probability of $\dfrac{1}{2^{10}}$. If we have LWWWWWWWWWW, that has probability $\dfrac{1}{2^{11}}$. Basically, the probability that any particular order of wins and losses has a probability of $\dfrac{1}{2^n}$ where $n$ is the number of games played.

So, I needed to figure out how many games were played in each of the $5^{10}$ valid scenarios. I know that if $x_1$ represents the number of wins that were not directly preceded by a loss, $x_2$ represents the number of wins directly preceded by exactly 1 loss, etc., then the total number of games played is $x_1+2x_2+3x_3+4x_4+5x_5$. And because there will be 10 wins total, I know that $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=10$. So, the question becomes, how many ways can I have $\{x_1\cdot W, x_2\cdot LW, x_3\cdot LLW, x_4\cdot LLLW, x_5\cdot LLLLW\}$. This is a multiset. Each permutation of this multiset (with multiplicity numbers $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$) represents a valid ordering of wins and losses. So, all that is left to do is calculate the number of permutations of this multiset, which is $\dfrac{10!}{x_1!x_2!x_3!x_4!x_5!}$.

This is where my formula came from. Each permutation of this multiset represents a valid ordering of a number of games equal to the sum of the multiplicities. It should be stated that:

$$\sum_{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)\in A}\dfrac{10!}{x_1!x_2!x_3!x_4!x_5!} = 5^{10}$$

is well-known. Basically, I am partitioning the set of $5^{10}$ where the probability of each element in a single partition is the same.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, I am attempting to wrap my brain around it now.

Comment: I updated my response. Hopefully what I added will help explain how I came to the formula I did and why it gives the correct answer.

Comment: Good stuff.  Thanks again.